# JabberGuest.h file not found

Tags: ios, frameworks, preprocessor

[image]
When I run my test code ,the complier just shows like the above:

and when I turn to the Project Navigator, find the framework has just one file where it should be a folder:
[image]

and the framework in the Finder is like this:

[image]

Comment: It seems your framework has some problem, maybe it's not enough files. After added, you must see the header files bellow framework: http://gyazo.com/145a686e421ac1b9e35716b2f294dc69. You can check this in framework folder: http://gyazo.com/c4a0a209d8fb7a34ebbb96868d3c217b

Answer (score 0):

Try following these steps:

1. Click on your project main file
2. Select your target
3. Click on Build Phases
4. Open Link Binary With Libraries
   See Screenshot
   [image: add here]
5. Add your `JabberGuest.framework` there
6. Clean the project
7. Build the project
8. Run it

Might be this help you. If your problem is still not solved then leave your comment below.

Comment: I just tried following your steps, but it still didn't work. Is it possible that something wrong with  the framework

Comment: Can you upload your project to github or some other repository & share the link so that I can help you out in solving your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please right click in this framework and copy to from this location and paste desktop or any location. then Build and clean your project. then drag n drop desktop to your project and check and give me response is it work or not.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not copy anything from the location in the project navigation.There is no "copy" in the right click context menu . And I tried "Command + C", it also did not work

Comment: the 3rd shortcut above

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all ideas.
I solved this problem now. There is something wrong with the framework.Maybe zipped in windows resulted in this.